# Loop through two lists and update elements of one

Tags: python, pandas

Looping through two equally sized lists of pd.series. If a series element in `lst_1` has all zeros AND the same indexed element in `lst_2` is `None`, how to update `None` element of `lst_2` with the element of `lst_1` in the same index?

```
# original lst_1 and lst_2
lst_1 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,0]), pd.Series([0,0,0,0]), pd.Series([2,0,2,0])]
lst_2 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,1]), None, pd.Series([2,2,0,0])]

# My try
for i, j in zip(lst_1, lst_2):
    if (i.all() == 0) and (j is None):
        j = pd.Series([0]*len(i))
        # have got this far...
```

Expected result:

```
lst_1 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,0]), pd.Series([0,0,0,0]), pd.Series([2,0,2,0])]
lst_2 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,1]), pd.Series([0,0,0,0]), pd.Series([2,2,0,0])]
```

Comment: Please update the error that you are getting.

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: You said you wanted to achieve something, and you have done some code, so you must be getting some error or wrong results, that's what I was asking what output are you getting.

Comment: I was not getting any error. I was just not able to update lst_2 with j

Comment: Got you, added some tweaks to your code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
for i in range(len(lst_1)):
    if (lst_1[i].all() == 0) and lst_2[i] is None:
        lst_2[i] = lst_1[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very small tweak would make it work:

```
lst_1 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,0]), pd.Series([0,0,0,0]), pd.Series([2,0,2,0])]
lst_2 = [pd.Series([1,0,1,1]), None, pd.Series([2,2,0,0])]

for index, i, j in enumerate(zip(lst_1, lst_2)):
    if (i.all() == 0) and (j is None):
        lst_2[index] = pd.Series([0]*len(i))
```